# How to extract items out of an array in Java, and place into another array, and calculate a total

Tags: java

Firstly, I'm doing this for one of my assignments, and I don't expect to be spoon fed. Just some guidance in the correct direction would be great.

I'm required to code a java application which opens a text file entered by the user, this text file contains the following data in it below.

(Grades.txt)

```
57363 Kuveshan D D C P H H C D
72992 Jason Green H H H D D H H H
71258 Mistey Norms C F C D C C C P
70541 Ben Dover F F F P C C C F
46485 Justin Time F C F C D P D H
61391 Anna Conda D D F D D F D D
88985 Bob Down P F P F P F P P
```

The above is: StudentID, Name, and then 8 letters: F, C, D, P, H (these are grades ie Fail, Credit, Distinction, Pass, High Distinction).

Below is the code I have written so far which opens the text file, and places each line from the text file into an array item.

```
    package accountFilesDemo_17259747;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This below is an the full path used for user to enter
 * path to grades
 * C:\\Users\\Vick\\PT\\accountFilesDemo_17259747\\src\\accountFilesDemo_17259747\\Grades.txt
 * yours (the markers) will be different
 * @author vkumar
 *
 */


public class StudentGPA_17259747 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter file name: ");

        // Get the file name from the user
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();
        String[] array = new String[100];
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)))
        {

            String sCurrentLine;
            int i = 0;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                array[i] = sCurrentLine;
                i++;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        // studentID array
        String[] studentID = new String[array.length];

        // student name array
        String[] studentName = new String[10];

        // student scores array
        String[] studentScores = new String[50];


        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            studentID[i] = array[i].substring(0, 5);System.out.println(studentID[i]);
        }

        //System.out.println(array[2]);
        // prints: 71258 Eileen Over C F C D C C C P
        //String[] studentID = new String[array.length];
        //for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        //{
        //  studentID[i] = array[i].substring(0, 5);
        //  System.out.println(studentID[i]);
        //s}


    }

}
```

Now, I was able to use a second array to store the "studentID" into, but what I'm struggling with is "what" can I do to get the ie " D D C P H H C D" part into an array or so with them equaling to

```
H = 7
D = 6
C = 5
P = 4
F = 0
```

I don't need the names for anything, I want to be guided on how I can get those 8 individual alphabet characters and assign them the numbers above. Once the text file has been opened and these have been read into the array, I need to get the studentID and the 8 letters then using these 8 letters I need to get their number values add them up (do the GPA formulas etc) and save a text file with:

studentid score
29292 3.4
^
Example.

Solutions are appreciated, feedback is appreciated, negative comments are appreciated too, but overall prefer guidance to good sources of examples, theory, readings, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: You are explained what a line contains. This is a logical unit of grouped data - or an **object**. Start again with that in mind. A `String[]` is not the correct data structure which is why you are having problems.

Comment: I suggest to use string.split method and it is better to use a HashMap to store the grades.

Comment: Is each grades are different number for each student ?

Comment: Grades are based on GPA ie 1 student gets F C C C which is fail, credit, credit credit, and another just gets F F F F which is 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 0, I've tried string.split and haven't had much luck finding a way to split them into useable variables or so, and Spider what do you mean it's not the correct data structure?

Comment: Its suggested to use HashMap (key & value ) pair to store the grades with respective alphabets.

Comment: All student id, name, marks are loaded from a text file so how do I load them from text file into HashMap?

Comment: Since this is an assignment I must ask: what are you allowed to use / what are you restricted from using? (Use @username to reply to someone's comments.)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have the letters stored in a String list. You just need to convert them into numbers
I suggest using an Enum for this. You can also convert the String list into Enum.

Try using this Enum as reference

```
public enum Grade {
    H(7), D(6), C(5), P(4), F(0);

    private int value;

    private Grade(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Grade getGrade(char ch) {
        switch (ch) {
        case 'H':
            return H;
        case 'D':
            return D;
        case 'C':
            return C;
        case 'P':
            return P;
        case 'F':
            return F;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```